# How to sync sql server login and database level permissions between 2 sql servers?

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

If I have log shipping configured between 2 sql servers on premise, then, in addition to the database data and schema, will the database user permissions and server login permissions/role membership get synced. Or is there any other configuration to achieve this?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [PowerShell ❤ SQL Server](https://dbatools.io) (dbatools.io) and then possibly the video they posted on their site: [Watch a SQL Server to SQL Server Migration](https://youtu.be/hg8tovMRX2k). **<= free**. There are other paid options that you could consider. Red-Gate SQL Compare being one. ApexSQL.com has some tools that might assist you with migration tasks. I'm in no way affiliated with these companies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Database users, roles, role memberships, and permissions are stored in the database and will be transferred by log shipping.

SQL Logins would need to be synchronized between the instances using a different mechanism.  See eg [Transfer logins and passwords between instances of SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/security/transfer-logins-passwords-between-instances)

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do you know whether the script from that link is idempotent. That is - can be run several times without any negative effect?